# Ask some issues of local deployment of forge

Tags: autodesk

I want to ask, if forge uses local files, does it only support the SVF format file?
If I want to deploy in the local area, can I do it? I mean uploading the file in the RVT format to my server, and then can I do it through the Viewer3d.js in the Viewer3d.js in the Forge?

I tried the local loading SVF file, but I want to load the RVT file, it prompts me not support, so where does the SVF file come from?